# Get an array of captures from a regex search in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

Let's say I have this string:

```
"14 be h90 bfh4"
```

And I have this regex pattern:

```
"(\w+)\d"
```

In PowerShell, how do I get an array with the contents `{"h", "bfh"}`?

Comment: i am not very good with regex but im trying to learn. Is this what you want? `$array = ($string -split '(\s)') -replace '[^a-zA-Z-]','' | SELECT-STRING -Pattern '([A-Z])' `

Comment: Try `$result = Select-String '\b(\p{L}+)\d+\b' -Input "14 be h90 bfh4" -AllMatches|%{$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}`

Answer (score 2):

You want to capture one or more alphabets that are followed by a number, hence the regex for what you want to capture would be this,

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?=\d)
```

And the powershell code for same will be this,

```
$str = "14 be h90 bfh4"
$reg = "[a-zA-Z]+(?=\d)"
$spuntext = $str | Select-String $reg -AllMatches |
            ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
echo $spuntext
```

**Disclaimer:** I barely know powershell scripting language so you may have to tweak some codes.

Comment: The powershell part does need rework but the gist of it looks good

Comment: Thanks @LievenKeersmaekers. I actually just googled about powershell and came up with this. I've never got a chance to use powershell before. But its good, everything has a first time :)

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorten version:

```
@(Select-String "[a-zA-Z]+(?=\d)" -Input "14 be h90 bfh4" -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to skin a cat as demonstrated by the other answers. Yet another way would be by using the `[regex]` object provided by .Net

```
$regex = [regex] '([a-z]+)(?=\d+)'
$regex.Matches("14 be h90 bfh4") | Select Value
```